# Saving PDF files to desktop [VB .NET]

Tags: vb.net

I want to save PDF files to my desktop. This code I have saves them in the bin folder

```
Dim pdf = gvwProyectos.SelectedRows.Count > 0
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4)
        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("Reporte.pdf", FileMode.Create))
```

I'm using iTextSharp btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's desktop path using `Environment.GetFolderPath`, then prefix your file name with it.

To use `Path.Combine` you need to add `Imports System.IO` before your form class if you haven't already done so.

```
Dim pdf = gvwProyectos.SelectedRows.Count > 0
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4)
Dim filename As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Reporte.pdf")
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
```

Comment: I got lucky and find out how to do it, but thanks for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I already find out how to do it but I'll leave what worked for me in here.

```
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4)
        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\" + "yourPDFdesiredName.pdf", FileMode.Create))
```