# How to saving PDF files to a folder ? vb.net or itsharptext

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I create a table in iTextSharp, all goods, but i want to save in specfific folder;

My code are:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & so & ".pdf")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 0.0F, 0.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)

    pdfDoc.Open()
```

HERE CODE!!!
Here i put my code and create PDF and i finish with:

```
    pdfDoc.Close()

    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.[End]()
```

Where i put my location like that:

> "\art-fs02\07_ART_ECO\12_Samples\03_Samples_order\01_Samples_BOMs_&_DRW\"

Answer (score 0):

Just use FileStream to save your document.

```
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4)
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\" + "yourPDFdesiredName.pdf", FileMode.Create))
```

[Saving PDF files to desktop [VB .NET]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351243/saving-pdf-files-to-desktop-vb-net)